# CPP : Difference between string.find()==0 and string.find !=string::npos

Tags: c++

```
Command* Function(const char* cmd_line) {

    string cmd = _trim(string(cmd_line));
    if(cmd.find(">") != string::npos)
    {
        return new something(cmd_line);
    }
  else if (cmd.find("pwd") == 0) {
    return new something1(cmd_line);
  }
  else if (cmd.find("chprompt") == 0){
      return new something2(cmd_line);
  }
...
```

Why when I change the first IF condition to cmd.find(">")==0, my program does not work. It only works with cmd.find != npos.
It seems like there is no difference between the two If statements logically, so it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: 0 is the beginning of the string, and a valid position when found.

Comment: You did not show what `cmd_line` is actual set to.

Answer (score 3):

`find()` returns the position where the substring is found.

If the substring is found at position 0 (i.e. at the exact beginning
of the string), then 0 is returned and it is not a failure.

`npos` is a special value, not suitable for any valid position in the string, and is used to report a failure when the substring is not found.

Comment: Didn't really get it.
Suppose I am providing a string -with- ">":
It is entering the first kind of IF statement,  if(cmd.find(">") != string::npos)
However, in some odd manner, it does not recognize the second IF statement,
if(cmd.find(">") ==0)
Could you explain why please?
P.S. Suppose it is not the first character in the sentence provided.

Comment: @maor36a Supposing it's *not* the first character, how could its position be 0 when 0 is - by definition - the position of the first character?

Comment: @maor36a I'm not certain I understand the question in your comment. Entering the first `if()` (for whatever reason) leads to executing the first return statement. At this moment, any following statement will be skipped. The second `if()` will not even be tested; moreover it is in the `else` part of the first `if()`.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` returns the index of the substring if it is found, otherwise `npos` (-1) is returned.

`cmd.find(">") == 0` will be true only if `">"` is found *at the very beginning* of `cmd`, eg `"> command here"` but not `"command > here"`, etc.

`cmd.find(">") != string::npos` will be true if `">"` is found *anywhere* in `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are Arrays and therefore 0 is a valid answer.
For Example(no real code):

```
"Hallo World".find("Hallo")
```

would return 0 beacuse the word is found at index 0.